# How can I share Internet Connection among two Linux computers using firewire running Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, connection-sharing, firewire

I have two computers (let say "A" and "B") that are already pinging and sshing each other via firewire, both with static ip. Computer A is connected to the Internet and I want it to share its internet connection to computer B. I have no idea of how this can be done via firewire interface. Any ideas? thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

Computer [A]:

- enable IP forwarding

  - temporarily by running `echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`
  - or permanently by adding `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` in `/etc/sysctl.conf`
- iptables rules, assuming *eth0* is your interface to the internet and firewire0 the internal connection to comp [B] (to make them permanent, add them to `/etc/rc.local` before the *"exit 0"*:

`/sbin/iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
/sbin/iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o firewire0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
/sbin/iptables -A FORWARD -i firewire0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT`

Computer [B]:

- check for a valid DNS server in `/etc/resolv.conf`, if not add a line with `nameserver 8.8.8.8`
- make sure the default route is through comp [A] (`route -n` shows computer [A] IP's on the line with destination 0.0.0.0). if not, run `route del default; route add default gw COMPUTER_A_IP_ON_firewire0`